# Video Uploading Issue from Google Cloud Storage to YouTube

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, web-testing, invalid-argument, video-upload

I'm reaching out because our development team has been encountering difficulties while attempting to upload videos from Google Cloud Storage to YouTube.

Allow me to give you a short but precise description of how we upload videos. We first upload the videos to cloud storage and then upload them to YouTube. Meanwhile, the last step always fails. With so much information and support online, we were wondering whether it's likely that the impediment is coming from YouTube. We work with cloud storage as it's impossible for us to upload videos larger than 1 GB to YouTube locally. Any video larger than 1 GB that we try to upload from our website is automatically blocked. Is this normal?

Here is the Code:

```
  $client = new \Google_Client(); 

        $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/../../client_secret_2_38281876600-3dhoq8fbas87jg5aspseh4shnkqqpt5r.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'); 

        $client->setScopes([ 

            \Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE, 

            \Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_UPLOAD, 

        ]); 

        $client->setAccessType('offline'); 

        $token = $this->qi->RefreshtokenYoutube($this->qi->getSetting('token_upload_youtube')); 



        $client->setAccessToken($token->access_token); 





        $storage = new StorageClient([ 

            'keyFilePath' => __DIR__ . '/../../Website-project-57c7dfb2ba06.json' 

        ]); 



        $youtube = new \Google_Service_Youtube($client); 





        $video = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Video(); 

        $videoSnippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet(); 

        $videoSnippet->setTitle('Título del video'); 

        $videoSnippet->setDescription('Descripción del video'); 

        $videoSnippet->setTags(['etiqueta1', 'etiqueta2']); 

        $video->setSnippet($videoSnippet); 



        $videoStatus = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus(); 

        $videoStatus->setPrivacyStatus('public'); 

        $video->setStatus($videoStatus); 

        $objectName = 'videos/20210810_104146.mp4'; 

        $bucket = $storage->bucket($this->bucket); 

        $object = $bucket->object($objectName); 





        //$videoPath = __DIR__."/../../20210713_165033.mp4"; 



        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 







        //$client->setDefer(true); 

        $client->setDefer(false); 



        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet', $video); 



        $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload( 

            $client, 

            $insertRequest, 

            //$object->info()['contentType'], 

            'video/*', 

            null, 

            true, 

            $chunkSizeBytes 

        ); 

         $media->setFileSize($object->info()['size']); 

        //$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath)); 





        $status = false; 

        /*$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb"); 

        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) { 

            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes); 

            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk); 

        }* 



        fclose($handle);*/ 





        $gcsStream = $object->downloadAsStream(); 







        while (!$media->nextChunk()) { 

            $chunk = $gcsStream->read($chunkSizeBytes); 



            if ($chunk === false) { 

                break; 

            } 



           $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk); 

        } 

        $gcsStream->close(); 

   //$client->setDefer(false); 

        // Obtener el ID del video 

    dd($status); 

        $videoId = $status['id']; 

        dd($videoId); 

    /*} catch (\Google_Service_Exception  $e) {
```

Here's the error we get when uploading a video to YouTube from Cloud Storage:

[HTTP 500 Internal Server Error when uploading videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMK9G.png)

The error displayed during execution is by no means precise, nor is it conclusive enough to detect and correct the error.

What is disconcerting is that on the YouTube page the video has a pending status, as if YouTube were blocking the video pending approval.

[YouTube Channel showing Pending Videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcoXv.png)

So, is this normal? Is it necessary to make a request to you? To be able to perform this type of operation on YouTube.

We tried to upload videos from our Website to Google Cloud Storage to YouTube. The reason is because we can't upload videos bigger than 1GB from our Website to YouTube.

We were expecting by adding Google Cloud Storage it will transfer to YouTube successfully without any issues.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code